# Why parameter multi doesn't work in mongo request?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I try to update several items in mongo collection with a single request:

```
// [1, 2, 3] - numbers array.
const days = req.body.days;

const updated = await Item.update(
    {shift: shiftId, day: {$in: days}},
    {multi : true},
    {update: {
        name: 'one value for all objects witch corresponding condition',
    },
    function(err, docs) {
        console.log(docs);
    }
);
```

This Item schema:

```
const itemSchema = new Schema({
    shift: {
        ref: 'shift',
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true
    },
    day: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    name: {
        type: String
    }
});
```

But then I call this code updating only one objects.
I had many `Items` with have the same `shift`. But every `Item` had a unique day and I need update all `Items` which contains in days array.

For example, if we have `shiftId = 'abc'` and `days = [1, 2]`, I need update  all Items which have `shiftId = 'abc'` and have `day = 1 OR day = 2` both should be updated.

Why my solution have unexpected behavior and updating only one object meanwhile I set `{multi : true}`? How to fix it? Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**`multi: true`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) is the last parameter in an update query and you have used it second parameter.

So you have to use [**`multi: true`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) in last parameter and need to use [**`$set`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) to update a field.

```
const updated = await Item.update(
  { "shift": shiftId, "day": { "$in": days }},
  { "$set": { "name": "one value for all objects witch corresponding condition" }},
  { "multi": true }
)
```